# Recursively grouping symlinks by original file

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I've got a list in a text file similar in structure to the following:

```
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/schedtop");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/sendevent");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/setconsole");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/setenforce");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/setprop");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/setsebool");
symlink("mksh", "/system/bin/sh");
```

What I want to do is change them, using a Bash script, to be like the following:

```
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/schedtop", "/system/bin/sendevent", "/system/bin/setconsole", "/system/bin/setenforce", "/system/bin/setprop", "/system/bin/setsebool")
symlink("mksh", "/system/bin/sh");
```

This means grouping the lines and merging them based on the original file, in this case, `toolbox`.

Currently I'm just sorting the file by name, but that's not satisfactory, of course! Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` is well suited for such grouping tasks, e.g.:

```
$ awk -F'"' ' { a[$2]=a[$2] ", \""$4"\"" } 
        END { for(i in a) printf("symlink(\"%s\"%s);\n", i, a[i]); }' input
```

The output for your example:

```
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/schedtop", "/system/bin/sendevent",
                   "/system/bin/setconsole", "/system/bin/setenforce", 
                   "/system/bin/setprop", "/system/bin/setsebool");
symlink("mksh", "/system/bin/sh");
```

(line breaks added for better layout)

Where `-F'"'` instructs `awk` to interpret the double quote character as field delimiter. `$2` etc. reference the 2nd etc. field, for each line an entry is added/modified to the associative array `a`. The `END` action iterates over each key of the associative array and pretty prints the groups.